# como puedo acionar un if con un boton

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, variables, condiciones

hola trato de que con un boton se cambie de valor que ya se tiene predeterminado, lo eh estado intentando con un if y con una funcion de condicion alguna sugernecia

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="pin1" onclick="pin1">numero1</button>
    <input type="button" onclick="Sumar();" value="Calucular">
    <script>
            if  (function pin1){
                var n1 = 81;
            }
            else {
                var n1 = 72;
            }
        }
    var n2 = 21;
    function Sumar() {
            var suma = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2);
            alert("La suma es: "+suma)
        }
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para que la comunidad entienda mejor su pregunta, debe leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Luego [edit] la pregunta.

Comment: Puedes detallar todo el problema? osea el problema o enunciado que quieres resolver con Javascript, quizás te podamos orientar hacia otra solución mas adecuada.

Comment: Hola @Davidrj, tambien digo lo mismo, podrías ser más claro, no entiendo bien tu pregunta. Explícame más que todo el "if", ya que no sé que es lo que se esta evaluando.

Comment: pin1 no está definido

Answer (score 1):

Según lo entendido en tu programa al presionar el botón **numero1** tiene que cambiar el valor de la variable n1 a 81, de lo contrario vale 72.

Luego, al presionar el botón calcular tiene que sumar el valor anterior con la variable n2 que vale 21 en este caso mi solución seria la siguiente, utilizando javascript:

1. En el código HTML añadir la propiedad `id="nombre"` a ambos botones en, para luego utilizarla en javascript.

Luego en javascript:

2. declarar una variable y asignarle el valor de la funcion `document.getElementById("nombre_del_id")` para importar a javascript ambos botones.
3. En ambas variables utilizar la función `.addEventListener("click", nombre_de_la_funcion)`, la misma necesita dos parámetros: el nombre del evento al cual van a responder (en este caso el click) y el nombre de la función la cual ejecutarán en caso de que ocurra el evento anterior. Al escribir el nombre de la función no coloques paréntesis.
4. De esta manera si se oprime el botón, javascript reconocerá el click que se hizo a ese botón y ejecutará la función que le asignamos.
5. Y ya que definimos en un principio que n1 valía 72, **Solamente** en el caso de que se oprima el botón la variable n1 valdrá 81.
6. Luego se puede oprimir el botón calcular y realizará la operación con el valor correspondiente.

NOTA: Modifique un poco la información de tu alert() para que notes si hay un cambio en la variable n1 o no.

```js
var boton_numero1 = document.getElementById("pin1");
var boton_de_calcular = document.getElementById("boton_calc");

boton_numero1.addEventListener("click", cambio_valor);
boton_de_calcular.addEventListener("click", Sumar);

var n1 = 72;
var n2 = 21;

function cambio_valor() {
  n1 = 81;
}

function Sumar() {
  var suma = n1 + n2;
  alert("La suma de: " + n1 + " + " + n2 + " es igual a " + suma);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="pin1">Numero1</button>
    <input type="button" id="boton_calc" value="Calucular">
</body>
</html>
```